# MYSQL: get average price on mondays ordered by time

Tags: mysql

How can I get the average price on Monday grouped by time (every hour)

Table looks like:

| date | price |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-15 23:00:00 | 0.13 |
| 2023-01-15 22:00:00 | 0.18 |
| 2023-01-15 21:00:00 | 0.16 |
| 2023-01-15 20:00:00 | 0.20 |
| .... |  |
| 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 0.15 |

I tried query below:

```
SELECT date, AVG(price) as 'Monday'
FROM table
WHERE YEAR(date) = '2022' AND WEEKDAY(date) = 1
GROUP BY date_format(date, '%HH:%mm')
```

But it returns only the first monday of each month.

Expected result should be like this (probably I have to create 7 queries, each for one weekday):

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEnTM.jpg)

Comment: [WEEKDAY: Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday). Returns NULL if date is NULL.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday:~:text=Returns%20the%20weekday%20index%20for%20date%20(0%20%3D%20Monday%2C%201%20%3D%20Tuesday%2C%20%E2%80%A6%206%20%3D%20Sunday).%20Returns%20NULL%20if%20date%20is%20NULL.), and you seem to be GROUPing on month? (Please check the results for `date_format(date, '%HH:%mm')` )

Comment: Monday should have the full average till that moment? or the average since last monday? Or should it have the average till the next monday? Consider updating your post to include full details and reformat your input and output to be actual tables (both) and be full standalone samples that can help with query troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(MIN(`date`), "%Y-%m-%d"), HOUR(`date`), AVG(`price`) as 'Monday'
FROM `table`
WHERE YEAR(`datetime`) = "2023" AND WEEKDAY(`datetime`) = 0
GROUP BY HOUR(`datetime`);
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gWMeq6hkn8oVqmwz9ryF9J/0

Comment: Thanks, but this selects only the first Monday, I'm looking for all Mondays in 2022

Comment: @Joost change the 2023 in `WHERE YEAR('datetime') = "2023"` in 2022. Just add some more mondays for the INSERT in the DBFiddle and you will see that his SELECT is the correct answer.

Comment: @Sam020 and Piemol you are right! (ofcourse ;) ). Now I have to find a way how to plot the data in Time series in Grafana